# ERROR Type Error: Cannot convert null value to object

Tags: reactjs, expo, project, native

I am using reactive-native-SQLite-storage, using expo project I wanted to register using register credentials ,this is error

```
LOG  OPEN database: ibus.db
 LOG  OPEN database: ibus.db
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object

This error is located at:
    in RegistrationPage (at SceneView.tsx:132)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:124)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:218)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:281)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:279)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:45)
```

After reading documentation and watching different solution and I imported  and install SQLite  using npx expo install expo-sqlite, I clear  node_module all by using npm start -- --reset-cache

this are code

> ```
> import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
> import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';
> import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
> import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
> import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
>
> const RegistrationPage = () => {
>   const navigation = useNavigation(); 
>   const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
>   const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
>   const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
>
>   const db = SQLite.openDatabase({ name: 'ibus.db', location: 'default' });
>
>   const initializeDatabase = () => {
>     db.transaction(tx => {
>       tx.executeSql(
>         `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
>           id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
>           username TEXT UNIQUE,
>           password TEXT,
>           email TEXT,
>         );`
>       );
>     });
>   };
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     initializeDatabase();
>   }, []);
>
>   const registerUser = (username, password, email, onSuccess, onError) => {
>     db.transaction(tx => {
>       tx.executeSql(
>         'INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
>         [username, password, email],
>         (_, results) => {
>           console.log('User registered successfully');
>           onSuccess();
>         },
>         error => {
>           console.error('Error registering user:', error);
>           onError(error);
>         }
>       );
>     });
>   };
>
>   const handleRegistration = () => {
>     if (!username.trim() || !email.trim() || !password.trim()) {
>       Alert.alert('Error', 'Please fill all fields');
>       return;
>     }
>     registerUser(username, password, email, () => {
>       navigation.navigate('Login');
>     }, (error) => {
>       console.error('Error registering user:', error);
>       Alert.alert('Error', 'Registration failed. Please try again.');
>     });
>   };
>
>   return (
>     <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
>       <View style={{ width: '80%' }}>
>         <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 16 }}>
>           Register an Account
>         </Text>
>
>         {/* Username Input */}
>         <View style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
>           <Text style={{ marginBottom: 4 }}>Username</Text>
>           <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'gray', borderRadius: 8, padding: 8 }}>
>             <MaterialIcons name='person' size={18} color={'#333'} style={{ marginRight: 8 }} />
>             <TextInput
>               style={{
>                 flex: 1,
>               }}
>               placeholder="Username"
>               value={username}
>               onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
>             />
>           </View>
>         </View>
>
>         {/* Email Input */}
>         <View style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
>           <Text style={{ marginBottom: 4 }}>Email</Text>
>           <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'gray', borderRadius: 8, padding: 8 }}>
>             <MaterialIcons name='email' size={18} color={'#333'} style={{ marginRight: 8 }} />
>             <TextInput
>               style={{
>                 flex: 1,
>               }}
>               placeholder="Email"
>               value={email}
>               onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
>             />
>           </View>
>         </View>
>
>         {/* Password Input */}
>         <View style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
>           <Text style={{ marginBottom: 4 }}>Password</Text>
>           <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'gray', borderRadius: 8, padding: 8 }}>
>             <MaterialIcons name='lock' size={18} color={'#333'} style={{ marginRight: 8 }} />
>             <TextInput
>               style={{
>                 flex: 1,
>               }}
>               placeholder="Password"
>               value={password}
>               onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
>               secureTextEntry
>             />
>           </View>
>         </View>
>
>         {/* Register Button */}
>         <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleRegistration} style={{ backgroundColor: '#3498db', padding: 10, borderRadius: 8 }}>
>           <Text style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>Register</Text>
>         </TouchableOpacity>
>       </View>
>     </View>
>   );
> };
>
>
> export default RegistrationPage;
> ```